# Why is $\mathbb{Z}$ path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I understand a space $X$ is path-connected if there exists a path $\tau$ for every point $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $\tau(0)=x_1,\tau(1)=x_2$. And a path must be continuous.

Well, I cannot find a path in $\mathbb{Z}$. Say $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
I thought of $\tau(t)=(1-t)z_1+tz_2$ but then, $t,1-t$ will be non-integers at somepoint hence $\tau(t) \not\in \mathbb{Z}$(at least, not for all $t$) meaning that there isn't a continuous map, right? Or am I wrong?

Does my $\tau$ qualify as a path for $\mathbb{Z}$? If not, can someone give me an explicit example so I can get a clearer picture?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is not path connected in its usual topology.

Comment: It isn't even connected.

Comment: It's totally disconnected.

Comment: It's discrete (I don't think we can go further).

Comment: It is not path-connected. In fact, the only path-connected subsets of $\Bbb Z$ are singletons (i.e. sets with one element). This is the definition of _totally disconencted_. Since the path components of a totally disconnected set are the singletons, there are infinitely many path components: $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{-1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{-2\}$, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, $\mathbb{Z}$ is in fact *not* path connected: indeed, it's about as far from being path connected as it is possible to be!

What is true is that it is *locally path connected*: given any point $x$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which is path connected. This is silly, though: that "open neighborhood" is just $\{x\}$! Any discrete space is locally path connected (as well as locally [basically anything]).

I'm curious where you heard that $\mathbb{Z}$ is path connected. Maybe the "locally" got lost along the way?

Comment: Maybe there is a useful topology in some context where $\mathbb{Z}$ is connected?

Comment: @Brian. Yes, there is : the cofinite (or Zariski) topology in which the closed sets are the finite sets and $\mathbb Z$ itself.

Comment: Hi there, um, I thought it is because, in a solution to a particular problem said "$\mathbb{Z}$ has an infinite number of path components" which means it has infinite paths connected sets of elements(yes?). So, is it that it has infinite path connected elements...but not all? Wow this is messing with my mind

Comment: @JohnTrail No. A "path component" is a subset of a space (usually a maximal subset of the space) which is path connected. Each singleton $\{z\}$ $(z\in\mathbb{Z})$ is a path component of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So, that's the case where for each singleton $\tau(t)=z$ defines a constant map and thus a path to itself? But is it's like I cannot define a path for $\{z_1,z_2\}$ for distinct integers?

Comment: @JohnTrail Exactly.